# Problems when automating tests in google

Tags: android

Problems when automating tests in google，I don't think this problem is general. You need to know what operations have been performed.

Galaxy S9 ANdroid8.0

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: UIAsyncWorker
12-18 11:46:41.832: E/AndroidRuntime(23306): Process: com.google.android.music:main, PID: 23306
12-18 11:46:41.832: E/AndroidRuntime(23306): java.lang.RuntimeException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean com.google.android.finsky.services.IMarketCatalogService.isBackendEnabled(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
12-18 11:46:41.832: E/AndroidRuntime(23306):    at com.google.android.music.utils.async.CallerTracker.reThrowExceptionWithCallerStackTrack(CallerTracker.java:32)
12-18 11:46:41.832: E/AndroidRuntime(23306):    at com.google.android.music.utils.async.TraceableRunnable.runLogged(TraceableRunnable.java:23)
12-18 11:46:41.832: E/AndroidRuntime(23306):    at com.google.android.music.utils.async.LoggedRunnable.run(LoggedRunnable.java:30)
12-18 11:46:41.832: E/AndroidRuntime(23306):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
12-18 11:46:41.832: E/AndroidRuntime(23306):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
12-18 11:46:41.832: E/AndroidRuntime(23306):    at com.google.android.music.utils.LoggableHandler.dispatchMessage(LoggableHandler.java:74)
12-18 11:46:41.832: E/AndroidRuntime(23306):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
12-18 11:46:41.832: E/AndroidRuntime(23306):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
12-18 11:46:41.832: E/AndroidRuntime(23306): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean com.google.android.finsky.services.IMarketCatalogService.isBackendEnabled(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
12-18 11:46:41.832: E/AndroidRuntime(23306):    at com.google.android.music.tutorial.SignupStatus.checkStoreAvailable(SignupStatus.java:217)
12-18 11:46:41.832: E/AndroidRuntime(23306):    at com.google.android.music.tutorial.SignupStatus.doCheck(SignupStatus.java:155)
12-18 11:46:41.832: E/AndroidRuntime(23306):    at com.google.android.music.tutorial.SignupStatus.launchVerificationCheck(SignupStatus.java:130)
12-18 11:46:41.832: E/AndroidRuntime(23306):    at com.google.android.music.tutorial.SignupStatus.launchVerificationCheckWithFallbackTask(SignupStatus.java:114)
12-18 11:46:41.832: E/AndroidRuntime(23306):    at com.google.android.music.AccountsBroadcastReceiver$1.run(AccountsBroadcastReceiver.java:32)
12-18 11:46:41.832: E/AndroidRuntime(23306):    at com.google.android.music.utils.async.TraceableRunnable.runLogged(TraceableRunnable.java:21)
12-18 11:46:41.832: E/AndroidRuntime(23306):    ... 6 more
```

Comment: Seems null pointer exception. Please give more description like the code base where it is triggered

Comment: Google only gave me so much information

Comment: got the same report from the device 'Motorola moto e5 play'

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Any solution for this?